# How do I transfer pictures from my iPhone 6 to my Mac while phone is water damaged?

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 6 has been water damaged causing me not to see my screen, I can't unlock my phone because of this. Is there a way I can transfer my photos to my Mac without unlocking the phone?

Comment: If someone lends you another iPhone 6 you can make notes of the location of the unlock pattern to replicate on yours, given the digitizer still works of course.

Comment: So, is just the digitizer not working, or is it the whole iPhone?

Comment: Have you managed something?

Answer (score 1):

If your iPhone has trusted your Mac, turn your iPhone on, plug it into your Mac using an USB cable, start the application `Image Capture` and from there you can import all your photos.

I have tried now on my iPhone and does not ask me to unlock my phone or any other stuff like that.

I guess the only condition is that your iPhone has been connected to your Mac in the past.

Please let me know if that worked for you.